# Showing last 4 values based on filter Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I have some Retirement fund data which I visualize with scatterplots and bar charts. 
I am filtering the data with a Year slicer and a quarter filter (and fund type, but this is not relevant).

In my report I have 6 visuals, 4 of which are quarterly data, and two are yearly data.

I am using a bar chart visual to show certain values like the following:
[image]

My visual shows Quarter data for the selected Year. ( for example: it shows the invested equity per quarter for the year 2018)

However, for 2019 only 3 quarters are yet recorded.

Is it possible (for 2019) to show 3 quarters of 2019 and the last quarter of 2018 so that my bar chart still shows 4 quarters?

If so, could i make it  so that the year is also visualized on the x axis so that one may not get confused as to what year the quarter is from? (i.e. show Q4 2018 and Q1, Q2, Q3 2019)

Comment: Do you have a calendar table driving the dates? or are all the dates in the data?

Comment: I have dates in all tables and a calendar table with a relationship to all other tables. I use the calendar table for filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to have a current month indicator in your calendar table, which then counts back and forward in time. This [example](https://github.com/itconsultantonthedge/PowerQueryCalendar/blob/master/Power%20Query%20Calendar.txt) is based on Power Query and has current month and years/quarters/months ago. So for example March would be 0, Feb would be -1 etc.

You could also use something like in DAX as a calculated column:

```
Months = DATEDIFF([start],[end],MONTH)
```

with the Start being NOW() and the end the date in your calendar table

When the report refreshes it will recalculate the months ago and filter the visual so it will always correctly show the current Nth months you select. You could also use TOP, but if the calendar has dates in the future it might return those.

[image: Rolling Month Example]

The top visual displays the unfiltered visual, the bottom with the 'Months ago' of 0, -1, -2, -3

Comment: Thank for the answer. This seems like very usefull insight! However, and I might be incorrect here, does this return the past 4 months based on the filter or on the current date? For example, I select 2017, so the visual returns all quarters for 2017? Can i change out NOW() in the dax formula for the value selected in the filter or is this not possible?

Comment: Its based on the filter, if you need a more dynamic one, you'll have to use the TOP function